# How to use cookies in android

Tags: android, cookies

I want to store username and password for my project....
For the first time, user must be login with username and password.
After that, i want to store username and password as cookies.
When user logout, I want to ask with Dialog
" By logging out, Your username and password(cookie) will be delete,
and You must be relogin to access your account"...
If user logout, I want to delete his cookies..
If user login, I want to store his username and password as cookies..
Please give me any tutorial or code.....

Comment: [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) in android.

Answer (score 1):

Cookies are a web programming concept.  THey don't exist in Android.  Also, NEVER save the password in a cookie-  cookies are text files, they're totally unsecure.  You save an id that can be validated by the remote server but without giving a potential attacker direct login info.  In fact, nobody should ever save a password ever-  even servers should only save the hash of the password rather than the password itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SharePreferences](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_shared_preferences.htm)

What it does is that it will save your username and password even if the app quits but you can always delete it when you logout.